# HostListener mouseLeave and pointerLeave not triggered when element is hidden

Tags: javascript, css, angular, listener, hide

I'm sitting with a problem where I use the following 2 hostlisteners to call a close function on a element.

```
@HostListener(
        'pointerleave',
    )
@HostListener(
    'mouseleave',
)
```

The problem is, the icon it mouseleaves or pointerleaves, is a icon that is shown on hover of another element and hidden when no longer hovering, fixed with css.

My assumption is that if you leave the element fast enough, the display:none is set which will make the hostlisteners not called anymore, so the close function is no longer called.

Anyone has a fix for this?

Comment: Could you post more code please like the onclose function? Its hard to understand your problem without more code

Comment: As a shot in the dark would maybe `visibility: hidden` work instead of `display: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to have `pointer-events:none;` on the css somewhere which breaks this!